# jQuery get value from same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have this text inputs, dynamically generated by jquery. but basically, if you see from HTML POV, it look like this :

```
<div class="po-row">
    <input class="po-quantity">
    <input class="po-price">    
</div>

<div class="po-row">
    <input class="po-quantity">
    <input class="po-price">    
</div>

<div class="po-row">
    <input class="po-quantity">
    <input class="po-price">    
</div>
```

now, I want to do this calculation :

each po-row must have `subtotal`, calculated by `po-quantity * po-price`

all subtotal from each row will be summed into total. here's what I've done but only works for first row :

```
$(".po-row").each(function(){
    $(".po-price").blur(function(){
        var quantity = $(".po-quantity").val();
        var price = $(".po-price").val();
        var subtotal = quantity * price;
        $(".total").text(subtotal);
    });         
});
```

how to make jquery `each` literation works in this case? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to amend the logic to count all rows within the `blur()` handler, and restrict the selector to the price and quantity fields within the current row of the loop. Try this:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.po-price', function () {
    var subtotal = 0;
    $('.po-row').each(function() {
        var quantity = $(this).find(".po-quantity").val();
        var price = $(this).find(".po-price").val();
        subtotal += quantity * price;
    });
    $(".total").text(subtotal);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/muj6pbm6/)

Note that I used `document` as the primary selector in the example. For your working code you should use the closest parent element of `.po-price` which is available in the DOM on page load.

Comment: bro, your code works for me. but unfortunately those <div class="po-row"> is dynamically generated by jquery. so your code only works on visible .po-row. but not working on new po-row. any idea how to make it works to all .po-row?

Comment: You need to use delegated events in that case - answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

Change the order of `each` and `blur`. This will make the calculation run on each of the `.po-price` element's `blur` event.

```
$(".po-price").blur(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".po-row").each(function() {
        var quantity = $(".po-quantity").val();
        var price = $(".po-price").val();

        total += quantity * price;
    });
    $(".total").text(total); // Update the total
});
```

Comment: FYI You don't need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` here, as the multiplication operation will force type coercion for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try an each statement, using :first and :last to determine the input:

```
  var total = 0;
  $('.po-row').each(function() {
    total += $(this).find('input:first').val() * $(this).find('input:last').val();
  });
  alert(total);
```

```js
window.calc = function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.po-row').each(function() {
    total += $(this).find('input:first').val() * $(this).find('input:last').val();
  });
  alert(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="po-row">
  <input class="po-quantity">
  <input class="po-price">
</div>

<div class="po-row">
  <input class="po-quantity">
  <input class="po-price">
</div>

<div class="po-row">
  <input class="po-quantity">
  <input class="po-price">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
```